# Rename files in subfolder using name of parent folder

Tags: subdirectory, batch-rename

I have hundreds of files with **same name** present in multiple subfolders of the main folder. I want to **rename** them. For instance folder 1135_AS contains hundreds of subfolder (having a unique name) whose structure is like this:

1135_AS/Uod-1_6975/transcriptome/salmon/quant.sf

I want to rename **quant.sf** with the name of the **unique folder**

For instance:

> 1135_AS/Uod-1_6975/transcriptome/salmon/quant.sf

should be converted to :

> > 1135_AS/Uod-1_6975/transcriptome/salmon/Uod-1_6975_quant.sf

and

> 1135_AS/Urd-1_9901/transcriptome/salmon//quant.sf
>
> > 1135_AS/Urd-1_9901/transcriptome/salmon//Urd-1_9901_quant.sf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# cd into the parent dir, which is common:
$ cd 1135_AS/  

$ find . -type f -name quant.sf \
  | awk -F/ '{s=substr($0,0,length($0)-length($NF))}{system("mv " $0" "s$2"_"$NF)}'
```

- Use `find` to get print the full path of the file.
- `s=substr($0,0,length($0)-length($NF))` prints the entire path except
- `quant.sf` or the last field `$NF` Use `system(cmd)` in `awk` to mv
  the file.

One can see what the script is going to do by removing `system()`... It will print something like this,

```
$ find . -type f -name quant.sf \
  | awk -F/ '{s=substr($0,0,length($0)-length($NF))}{print "mv " $0" "s$2"_"$NF}'
mv ./Uod-1_6975/transcriptome/salmon/quant.sf ./Uod-1_6975/transcriptome/salmon/Uod-1_6975_quant.sf
```